# How to make checkboxes show up in contact form

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm fairly new to coding in PHP. Currently I am having a problem with my checkboxes and dropdown boxes submitting in my contact form.
I am using Bootstrap to build the site.
I've researched answers and I have not been able to find why my checkboxes won't show up in my email.

### Below is my code:

**Here is the PHP:**

```php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $branch = $_POST['Toledo Branch, Columbus Branch'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $companyname = $_POST['companyname'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $contacting = $_POST['Services/Solutions, Quote Request, Service Request, Other '];
    $area = $_POST['area-0, area-1, area-2, area-3, area-4, area-5 '];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];
    $from = 'ProVideo Website'; 
    $to = 'samantha@provideosystems.com'; 
    $subject = 'Message from ProVideo Contact Form ';

    $body = "Branch: $branch \ 
            From: $name \ 
            Company: $companyname \ 
            Title: $title \ 
            E-Mail: $email \ 
            Phone Number: $phone\ 
            Contacting About: $contacting \ 
            Interest: $area \
            Comment: $comment";

    // Check if name has been entered
    if (!$_POST['name']) {
        $errName = 'Please enter your name';
    }

    // Check if email has been entered and is valid
    if (!$_POST['email'] || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errEmail = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    // If there are no errors, send the email
    if (!$errBranch && !$errName && !$errCompanyname && !$errTitle && !$errEmail && !$errPhone && !$errArea && !$errComment ) {
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Thank You! We have received your message </div>';
        } else {
            $result='<div class="alert alert-danger">Sorry there was an error sending your message. Please try again later</div>';
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the Contact Form:**

```
<h3>Contact Us!</h3>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="branch">Choose a Branch to Contact</label>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <select id="contacting" name="contacting" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Toledo Branch</option>
      <option value="2">Columbus Branch</option>


    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->

<div class="form-group">

  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="name">Name</label>  

  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="First, Last" class="form-control input-md" required=""/>
    <?php echo "<p class='text-danger'>$errName</p>";?>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="companyname">Company Name</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="companyname" name="companyname" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md" required=""/>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="title">Title</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="title" name="title" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md"/>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="email">Email</label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="name@email.com" class="form-control input-md" required=""/>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="phone">Phone </label>  
  <div class="col-md-5">
  <input id="phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="(XXX) XXX-XXXX" class="form-control input-md" required=""/>

  </div>
</div>

<!-- Select Basic -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="contacting">I am contacting about...</label>
  <div class="col-md-5">
    <select id="contacting" name="contacting" class="form-control">
      <option value="1">Services/Solutions</option>
      <option value="2">Quote Request</option>
      <option value="">Service Request</option>
       <option value="">Other</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="area">Area of Interest</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="area-0">
      <input type="checkbox" name="area" id="area-0" value="1"/>
      Corporate
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="area-1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="area" id="area-1" value="2"/>
      Education
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="area-2">
      <input type="checkbox" name="area" id="area-2" value=""/>
      House of Worship
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="area-3">
      <input type="checkbox" name="area" id="area-3" value=""/>
      Government
    </label>
    </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="area-4">
      <input type="checkbox" name="area" id="area-4" value=""/>
      Sports Venue
    </label>
    <div class="checkbox">
    <label for="area-5">
      <input type="checkbox" name="area" id="area-4" value=""/>
      Other
    </label>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="comment">Comments</label>
  <div class="col-md-4">                     
    <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button -->
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="submit"></label>
  <div class="col-md-4">
<button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
 <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-10">

        </div>
    </div>

</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to display in the message, put the information in the value. I would also make the name an array so that you can use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop through all the check boxes to include them in the email.

```
 <div class="checkbox">
<label for="area-4">
  <input type="checkbox" name="area[]" id="area-4" value="Sports Venue"/>
  Sports Venue
</label>
```

Comment: Yep, pretty important adding [ ] to the name attribute so they're sent as an array

Answer (score 1):

You can't use this

```
$contacting = $_POST['Services/Solutions, Quote Request, Service Request, Other '];

$area = $_POST['area-0, area-1, area-2, area-3, area-4, area-5 '];
```

If you want to retrieve the value, you should use the name of the form element. In this case you're getting nothing because PHP won't recognize those array keys.

```
$area = $_POST['area'];
```

It might be **1** or **2** or **3** or **4**, etc, but I noticed in your HTML code, that you don't have a value for the rest of the checkboxes for all the areas, fixing that will help.

Same aplies to the line

```
$_POST['Services/Solutions, Quote Request, Service Request, Other '];
```

You just retrieve the value and do what you want with it but using this instead:
   $contacting = $_POST['contacting'];

HERE IS A TIP:

If you're not using more advanced data processing, you can simply leave the value of the option elements empty and the $_POST['contacting']; variable will return the String inside  tag.

For example:

```
<select name="contacting">
    <option>This option</option>
    <option>Another option</option>
    <option>Tacos y Quesadillas</option>
</select>
```

Whatever I choose will be send as one of those strings to the PHP instead of the value. It will be easier to concatenate them to your email body.

With the Checkboxes, you will need the value, indeed, just instead of numbers, use strings to make it easier again, to concatenate to your email body.

Comment: Great! This helps a lot! Thank you!